# minimum file size for correctly work exif_imagetype

Tags: php, image, validation

What is the minimum upload filesize needed for correct work `exif_imagetype()`?

---

On http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php no information about this.

Comment: What makes you think that filesize matters?

Comment: Oh yes. If the user uploads the 10 or 20 bytes, it will not image!

Comment: And what? Do you have code that tells the opposite?

Comment: No. I validated the image. When loading small files (NOT images). The error was, because the function could not read enough bytes to determine the file format.